# Redux nested state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have read many articles and examples, but I dont find a method to simplify a nested state. Is this possible to udpate a state without using a rest operator by property like the partial code below ?

```
const initialState = {
  currentTag: 'fr-FR',
  locales: {
    components: [],

  },
};

const setComponentsLocales = (state, payload) => ({
  ...state,
  [payload.oid]: payload.locales,
});

const localesReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.SET_COMPONENT_LOCALES:
      return {
        ...state,
        components: setComponentsLocales(state.components, action.payload),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.SET_LANGUAGE:
      return {
         ...state,
         currentTag: action.payload.tag,
      };
    default:
      return {
        ...state,
        locales: localesReducer(state.locales, action),
      };
   }
};
```

Comment: you can use `Object.assign` method if you don't like the spread operator

Comment: This is the same thing :) I dont want to use `Object.assign` on each property

Comment: you need to use immutability, so you don't have a lot of choices, `spread operator`, `Object.assign` or a library like [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)